# Flutter how to combine FutureBuilder and Consumer?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

i want to combine a `Consumer` with my `FutureBuilder`, so if we retrieve new data, only the `ListView.Builder()` should rebuild.
Now this is my function to call the data:

```
Future <List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>> getSongsOnce() async {
    var songsCollection = await db.collection('songs').get();
    var loadedSongs = songsCollection.docs.toList();

    return loadedSongs;
  }
```

Im calling the function in my `initState`

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
      Future<List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>> songFuture;
      FirestoreService db = FirestoreService();
      CollectionReference songs = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('songs');
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        songFuture = db.getSongsOnce();
      }
...
```

Now this is my `FutureBuilder` but I have multiple problems here:

```
Consumer<SongProvider>(builder: (context, sProvider, _) {
                  return FutureBuilder(
                      future: songFuture,
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          
    
                              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                                case ConnectionState.none:
                                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                                  return Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    child: CircularProgressIndicator()
                                  );
                                case ConnectionState.done:
                                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                    return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                                  } else {
    
                                    return ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return Text(
                                    snapshot.data[index]['songName'].toString());
                              });
                                  }
                              } 
                        }
```

The `return` of my Text has to be something like `sProvider.data[index]['songName'].toString()` but my `db.getSongsOnce();` doesnt give me something to acess there. Also I dont know what to write in my `itemCount` as I dont have anything inside `sProvider` or `db.getSongsOnce();` which gives me a length.